# How to count the number of rows above 3 Standard Deviation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've calculated the average and the standard deviation of certain fields in the data. Now, I'd like to count the number of rows whose value is above 3 Standard Deviation from the mean. The data table looks like this:

```
 ID      Frequency     Amount   Dept
A123        12           130     A
D324         7           154     D
D245        15           187     D
G423        23           210     G
E301        14           481     E
R492         9           140     R
```

Here's my code.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT t.*,
    STDEV([Frequency]) as freq,
    STDEV([Amount]) as amt,
    AVG([Frequency]) as freq_avg,
    AVG([Amount]) as amt_avg,
    AVG([Frequency) + 3*STDEV([Frequency]) as freq_3sd,
    AVG([Amount]) + 3*STDEV([Amount]) as amt_3sd
FROM MyTable t
)
SELECT count(*) 
FROM CTE
WHERE ([Frequency] >= as freq_3sd) AND ([trade_amount_usd] > as amt_3sd)
```

I calculated the 3 standard deviation above the mean for the Frequency and Amount columns in the CTE and tried to use those values as my thresholds to count the number of rows. However, it returns an error saying that I need to include "Group By" in my CTE query because of these two columns, ID and Dept, that I didn't use for the calculation in CTE. I don't think I can do the Group BY there because I want to get the avg, sd, and 3sd values of the entire dataset, not by ID or Department.

Should I calculate the 3SD values in one table and refer to those values in another table?

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer here. Make it easy to assist you!

Answer (score 1):

I only corrected your code(i used window function ),i could't to test result because I haven't your expected and you haven't column trade_amount_usd

```
  ;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT t.*,
    STDEV([Frequency]) over(order by (select 1)) as freq,
    STDEV([Amount]) over(order by (select 1)) as amt,
    AVG([Frequency]) over(order by (select 1)) as freq_avg,
    AVG([Amount]) over(order by (select 1)) as amt_avg,
    AVG([Frequency]) over(order by (select 1)) + 3*STDEV([Frequency]) over(order by (select 1)) as freq_3sd,
    AVG([Amount]) over(order by (select 1)) + 3*STDEV([Amount]) over(order by (select 1)) as amt_3sd
FROM myt t
)
SELECT count(*) 
FROM CTE
WHERE ([Frequency] >=  freq_3sd) AND ([trade_amount_usd] >  amt_3sd)
```